# Where does the spacing in Bootstrap button examples come from?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css

In the [Bootstrap 5 button examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags), there is a space between the buttons. I'am not sure where this space is defined and don't find any margin in the devtools:

[Devtools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BCBx.png)

Where does this space come from?

### Edit1

In my example (using **tailwind**) the space is missing despite of using `inline-block`. Is there a way to manipulate the spacing, or am I missing something.

[Devtools Screenshot of my `inline-block` buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INieP.png)

**Reproduced example:**

https://codepen.io/jjoharrer/pen/ZEyQWyo

Comment: `display: inline-block;` into `btn` class do the "trick"

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks, but in my test (without bootstrap) this space does not exist even when using `inline-block` (see Edit1).

Comment: You try to copy code for the space without using bootstrap?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'am currently learning tailwind and try to create my own (bootstrap orientated ;) styleguide. I know this seems to be a rather basic question, but I can't figure out why the spaces are missing in my example.

Comment: Post your code so.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I've added a code pen link https://codepen.io/jjoharrer/pen/ZEyQWyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the bootstrap example are all input instead of one button, if you just copy another button without that will be like your example. You need to re-create margin class like bootstrap:

```css
.button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
<div>
  <div>
    <button id="" class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-primary py-1 px-2 mr-2">Primary</button>
    <!--v-if--><button id="" class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-secondary py-1 px-2 mr-2">Secondary</button>
    <!--v-if--><button id="" class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-info py-1 px-2 mr-2">Info</button>
    <!--v-if--><button id="" class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-success py-1 px-2 mr-2">Success</button>
    <!--v-if--><button id="" class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-warning py-1 px-2 mr-2">Warning</button>
    <!--v-if--><button id="" class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-danger py-1 px-2 mr-2">Danger</button>
    <!--v-if-->
  </div>
</div>
```

in this case i use `mr-2` (margin right 2)

---

As you can see here if you go down (hit enter) with the code all work as expect so button will have a space else will be without space

```css
.button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-primary py-1 px-2 ">Primary</button>
    <button class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-primary py-1 px-2 ">Primary</button>
    <button class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-primary py-1 px-2 ">Primary</button><button class="button no-underline text-center rounded inline-block active button-primary py-1 px-2 ">Primary</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as to where is the space between blocks coming from, in their docs.

Comment: Yes, I'am aware of the `mr-2` utility class but as alex commented, I don't see such a utility class is used in the bootstrap docs. I don't fully understand what you mean with `As you can see in the bootstrap example are all input instead of one button`

Comment: Ah, the break (or space) in the source makes the difference. Somehow the break is removed in my vuejs component. Thanks!